# Force python installation into virtualenv

Tags: python, virtualenv, setuptools

I've got large python module that is particularly complex in terms of dependencies and on the Raspberry Pi it now conflicts with several core modules (pillow, pyserial, and a few others) which can't easily be overwritten. In general, installing into a virtualenv would be the best thing. But I've found that's a little beyond some users and as most users will simply use the CLI command that gets installed instead of the module API, I'd like to make things automatic. Is it possible, in any way, with setuptools to do the following?

- Automatically install virtualenv if not available
- Install module into virtualenv
- Install require dependencies into virtualenv
- Setup CLI command to run automatically from that virtualenv without first activating it

Comment: If you plan to install the package with `pip`, then there's no way to do that. If you are not averse against RPM or deb packages - I know that `rpmvenv` can create RPM packages containing virtual environments, and `fpm` [can bundle existing environments](http://fpm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/virtualenv.html), so you have a bundle of python packages installed aside the system ones. AFAIK, it can build a lot of formats, including RPM and deb. Installation via `pip install rpmvenv` and `gem install fpm` (it's a Ruby tool).

Comment: Interesting but doesn't seem to support Windows, which is a requirement. Though maybe there's another python packaging tool that will do similar. I'd love to keep pip support, but not the end of the world if not.

Comment: Hmm, with Windows in mind I'd also look at standalone installers built with `pyinstaller`/`cxFreeze` etc, however, I have very little experience with those. The best Windows option in my opinion would be writing a standalone installer with NSIS. In the installation script, you can create a fresh virtual environment, install the package along its dependencies in the env and adjust `PATH` so the installed executables are available. Unfortunately, the standard packaging tools (`distutils`/`setuptools`) are simply not powerful enough for that.

Answer (score 0):

For this I've created two scripts where are in a script directory.

Create venv:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd ..
virtualenv -p python3 --no-site-packages venv
cd script
sh updateEnv.sh
```

Update venv (based on a requirements.txt file):

```
#!/bin/bash
cd ..
echo "activating env"
. venv/bin/activate
pip install --upgrade -r requirements/requirements.txt
```

You just need to add a check if the venv folder is already created.
All you need is to install virtualenv.